# How to find files quickly?

Tags: android, file, search, mp3

I really need some help please!

I want to make a MP3 Player on Android and therefore I need to find all MP3 files in the storage.

So I search them recursively in my get MP3 method:

```
private void getMP3Files(Context context, String directory,ArrayList<MusicListArray> mp3_list){

MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
Uri uri;
byte[] album_art;
Bitmap bitmap;
/*File[] files = Directory.listFiles(new MP3FileNameFilter());
files = Directory.listFiles();*/

File folder = new File(directory);
for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || file.getName().endsWith(".MP3")) {
            uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(context,uri);
            String artist = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
            String title = file.getName();
            album_art = mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
            if(album_art != null){
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(album_art, 0, album_art.length);
            }else{
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
            if(bitmap == null){
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
            if (title.indexOf(".") > 0)
                title = title.substring(0, title.lastIndexOf("."));
            if(artist == null){
                artist = getString(R.string.unknown_artist);
            }

            mp3_list.add(new MusicListArray(title,artist,file,bitmap));
        }
    }else if(file.isDirectory()){
        getMP3Files(context, file.getPath(), mp3_list);
    }
}
Collections.sort(mp3_list);

/*for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++){
    mp3_list.add(new MusicListArray(files[i].getName(),"Test",files[i]));
}*/
//return mp3_list;
```

}

This is very slow and needs about 3 seconds everytime I start my app.

First question: How do I manage to reduce the taken time?
Second question: How to save the list in a file and load it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use an SQL database to store the metadata (including file location) of your mp3s. I should warn you that I have no experience with media on Android though. Basic Idea:

1) First Time use (or on a manual sync in settings) do a full 3 second sync -> look at `SharedPreferences` to store a key indicating first time use for your app

2) Store this meta information in a SQL database.

3) Make the app read from the database as this is much faster, especially if the table is designed correctly. Store things like cover art, file location, artist, title etc. You can also add things like number of times listened and stuff. In addition if you wrap your SQL layer into a content provider you can perform custom searches of all your music.

4) When app is running, run a background indexing service that finds new music, corrects changes/deletes etc. Look into android `Service`

The benefits of this is that your app will be much faster to the user, only need to load all the data once in the foreground and provide you with a lot more flexibility in terms of searching, song choice, custom data etc.

Comment: Woooooow I really have to learn a lot! :D Anyway, thanks for the suggestion! I will take a look at SQL and try to implement it. I'll let you know whether it's working. :)